# problem hibernate in web service

Tags: eclipse, web-services, hibernate, jsp, exception

[image]before reading my problem this work in a normal dynamic web project
i create a web service like this methode:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2Vjs8ylmFM
using CFX 2.4 and with the 2.5 dynamic web model version and when i run hibernate in this current client web project generated by the web service i get an exception 
this is it:

```
  Etat HTTP 500 - 

     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      type Rapport d''exception

      message 

      description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne () qui l'a empêché de satisfaire la                 requête.

       exception 

       org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Impossible de compiler la classe pour la JSP: 

        An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
        The type net.sf.hibernate.Session cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from         required .class files

         Une erreur s'est produite à la ligne: 16 dans le fichier jsp: /JSP/ebook/index.jsp
          Session cannot be resolved to a type
         13: <BODY> 
         14: <%
         15: 
         16: Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
         17: Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction(); 
         18: 
         19: Etudinat etudiant = new Etudinat();


         Une erreur s'est produite à la ligne: 16 dans le fichier jsp: /JSP/ebook/index.jsp
```

and my class hibernateUtil is :

```
package DBase;

import net.sf.hibernate.*;

import net.sf.hibernate.cfg.*;


 public class HibernateUtil {

 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 static {
 try {
 // Crée la SessionFactory
 sessionFactory =
 new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
 } catch (HibernateException ex) {
 throw new RuntimeException("Problème de configuration : "
 + ex.getMessage(), ex);
 }
 }

 public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

  public static Session currentSession()
  throws HibernateException {
  Session s = (Session) session.get();
 // Ouvre une nouvelle Session, si ce Thread n'en a aucune
 if (s == null) {
 s = sessionFactory.openSession();
 session.set(s);
 }
 return s;
}
```

and my hibernate.cfg.xml page is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-2.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory >

<!-- local connection properties -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebook</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">162826</property>
<!-- property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size"></property -->

<!-- dialect for MySQL -->
<property name="dialect">net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>



 <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <mapping resource="DBase/Favorieensei.hbm" />
  <mapping resource="DBase/Ajouter.hbm" />
  <mapping resource="DBase/Favorie.hbm" />
  <mapping resource="DBase/Enseignant.hbm" />
```

and this is my page jsp

```
<%@page import="DBase.HibernateUtil"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %> 
<%@ page import="DBase.*" %> 
<%@ page import="net.sf.hibernate.*" %> 
<%@ page import="net.sf.hibernate.cfg.*" %> 

<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
<title>Greetings!</title> 
</HEAD>  
  <BODY> 
<%

 Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
  Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction(); 

  Etudinat etudiant = new Etudinat();
  etudiant.setUserName("davido");
 etudiant.setPassword("mioo");
  etudiant.setQuestion("best music");
   etudiant.setAnswer("rock");
   etudiant.setEmail("david@live.fr");
  etudiant.setNom(".....");
  etudiant.setPrenom("....");
  etudiant.setSexe("Homme");

   etudiant.setIDFilliere(Filliere.INFORMATIQUE);
  hibernateSession.save(etudiant); 
  tx.commit();
  HibernateUtil.closeSession();


  %> 


  <br> 
 <br> 
 <br> 
 <br> 
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="tableBox"> 
  <tr> 
  <td CLASS="bluebanner" align="center"> Greetings, </TD> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
    </BODY> 
    </HTML>
```

plz help us we are running on time i have  3 left to finish it

Answer (score 1):

The file you label your jsp page is not a jsp page but a hibernate configuration file.

The problem is most likely in your classpath though.  The hibernate libraries are not on the classpath used to compile the java code generated from your jsp.

Comment: i use plugin hibernate for generating the classes